# How to know when to call a closure with () or without parentheses in handler:

Tags: swift

I have this code:

```
  func askQuestion(action : UIAlertAction! = nil){
    countries.shuffle()
    correctAnswer = Int.random(in: 0...2)
    
    button1.setImage(UIImage(named: countries[0]), for: .normal)
    button2.setImage(UIImage(named: countries[1]), for: .normal)
    button3.setImage(UIImage(named: countries[2]), for: .normal)
    
    title = countries[correctAnswer].uppercased()
    
 }

 @IBAction func buttonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
    var title:String
    
    if sender.tag == correctAnswer{
        title = "Correct"
        score += 1
    } else {
        title = "Wrong"
        score -= 1
    }
                                                                                 
    let ac = UIAlertController(title: title, message: "Your score is \(score)", 
    preferredStyle: .alert)
    
    ac.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Continue", style: .default, handler: askQuestion))
```

1.In last row how do i know when i need to add parentheses to closure ?

2.Do i always have to add
(action : UIAlertAction! = nil) to askQuestion func when calling closure to handler?

Answer (score 1):

> In last row how do i know when i need to add parentheses to closure ?

The question makes no sense. Add *what* parentheses?

The `handler:` parameter value is a *function*. You can supply it in two ways:

- A function reference. That is what you are doing (correctly): you have used `func` to define the function elsewhere, and now you are giving the *name* of the function as a reference. You do not put parentheses here; that would *call* the function. You just want to say *what* function it is.
- An anonymous function. That is curly braces. You can give this in two ways:

  - Directly as the `handler:` parameter
  - Using trailing closure syntax

So, the following are all correct:

```
ac.addAction(
    UIAlertAction(
        title: "Continue", style: .default, handler: askQuestion))
```

or

```
ac.addAction(
    UIAlertAction(
        title: "Continue", style: .default, handler: { _ in
            self.countries.shuffle()
            // ...
        }
))
```

or

```
ac.addAction(
    UIAlertAction(
        title: "Continue", style: .default) { _ in
            self.countries.shuffle()
            // ...
        }
)
```

> Do i always have to add `(action : UIAlertAction! = nil)` to askQuestion func

No, I don't understand the point of that at all. Just say `_: UIAlertAction` if using a defined `func`. Note the syntax for the anonymous function examples, which is different.

Answer (score 1):

You add parentheses to a function when you call it, not when you pass a reference to it (unless it itself is generating the desired function when it is called).

You need the “action : UIAlertAction” part in this case because your function’s type has to match the expected type of the handler.  The ! = nil part is unnecessary because UIAlertAction is not optional (it isn’t followed by a ?, so the compiler knows that it shouldn’t be nil).  Better yet, put _: UIAlertAction because you are not using the parameter so it doesn’t need a name.

Comment: ...and you should avoid using the `!` operator  until you really understand it. (either declaring parameters/variables as "implicitly unwrapped optionals" as you are doing, or using "force unwrap". Both are dangerous and cause crashes if the underlying Optional is nil)